# google collabs /keras wont download data set propely

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

There's this code that's supposed to download a zip file which is the data set for the program. but whenever i use a link that's not the original one in order to download the data set it won't work.
Here's the original code:

```
path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
'spa-eng.zip', 
origin='http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/spa- 
eng.zip',
extract=True)
 path_to_file = os.path.dirname(path_to_zip)+"/spa-eng/spa.txt"
```

and here's the code i use:

```
  path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
'spa-eng.zip', 
  origin='http://www.mediafire.com/file/qqwie8xamhbjtuc/spa-eng.zip/file',
  extract=True)

  path_to_file = os.path.dirname(path_to_zip)+"/spa-eng/spa.txt"enter code 
  here
```

When i run the code i use it gives these results: 8192/Unknown, but when i use the original code it gives these results: 2646016/2638744.I can simply use the original link yes but that also means i cannot use other data sets because it won't get downloaded properly by the code. also i've used mediafire and google drive for the modified code and they have the same results and the whole program won't work if i use them.

Comment: Both links look identical to me.

Comment: oh shoot my bad, there we go i changed the link below to the link i used. so any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Both Google Drive and Mediafire will not give you a direct download through HTTP, unlike the first link, just open them in your browser and see that the first link directly downloads the file, while mediafire will need you to press a button to download. That won't work with any HTTP API.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on where i should store the files?